# Why does this happen: "AttributeError: shape"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

"Full" Code(not all but the important part):

```
video = VideoFileClip(r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\bac.mp4')
frames = []
video_duration = 3
for line in lines:
    if y_text < 560:
        draw.text(((40), 10 + y_text), line, font=font_type1, fill=color)
        y_text += height
        cropped = image.crop((0,0,image.width,y_text-4+(int(height/2))))
        frames.append(cropped)
    elif y_text2 < 560:
        draw2.text(((40), y_text2), line, font=font_type1, fill=color)
        y_text2 += height
        cropped2 = image2.crop((0,0,image.width,y_text2+4))
        frames.append(cropped2)


clips = []
for frame in frames:
    logo = (ImageClip(frame)
          .set_duration(video_duration)
          .set_position((0,0.10), relative=True))
    video = video.subclip(video_duration, video_duration*2)  
    final = CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
    clips.append(final)


video_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='chain')
video_clip.write_videofile(r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\VideoFolder\video-output.mp4', fps=24, remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

Explanation: In the `for line in lines` loop I edit some pictures and want to store the result in a list, then in the `for frame in frames:` loop I make them into videos which then I overlay over a background video, now this is where the problem arises, that being this error, even though if I first export these images into a folder and then import them from that folder to make the video; it works flawlessly, but as I want to that without the constant back and fourth between folders; I tried to make everything in one file, and now it does not work. I kinda have some clues on why it does not work, but no clues on how to fix it, so if you have any ideas; Thank you in advance.

Full Error:

```
  File "c:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\reddit-bot\body.py", line 78, in <module>
    logo = (ImageClip(frame)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 891, in __init__
    if len(img.shape) == 3:  # img is (now) a RGB(a) numpy array
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 546, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: shape
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69710537/edit) the question to include the full error traceback.

Comment: You iterate through frames but never actually use the frame. That seems odd

Comment: It seems when I copied the code I forgot to do some changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: error shows you in which line is problem - so use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you really have in variables. it is called `"print debuging"`. It seems you have something different in `frame` then you expect.

Comment: If I do that I get ```<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>```